# The meaning of the percent sign in LaTeX coding

Tags: macros, symbols, sourcecode, syntax, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines)

I know that `%` is commonly used to uncomment parts of the code, but recently I read that there is another use for the percentage sign but I don't remember what it was neither where I read it.

For example in the following code `%` was placed at the end of several lines. What does `%` do in this case? (If required, I will provide a MWE.)

```
\newif\ifintoc
\def\@schapter#1{%
  \if@twocolumn
    \if@at@twocolumn
      \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
    \else
      \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
    \fi
  \else
    \@makeschapterhead{#1}\@afterheading
  \fi
  \ifintoc
    \stepcounter{specialchapter}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thespecialchapter}#1}%
  \fi
}
```

Comment: This looks very much like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines. Please take a look and see if it helps: if so we will probably close this question as a duplicate, to keep the site organised.

Comment: @JosephWright You're right. You can close the thread (btw: can I close my threads myself?). When I typed in my question, **http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines** did not appear as a possible answer.